# Focaltech touchpad detected as ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, focaltech

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTSC1000:00 2808:509C                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse               id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0Camera: USB 2.0Camera              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

output of

```
dmesg | grep PNP
```

```
[    0.268113] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
[    0.271227] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
[    0.377020] system 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.377264] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.377358] system 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs INT3f0d PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.378720] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active)
[    0.378808] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs FTE0001 PNP0f13 (active)
[    0.379404] system 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.379529] system 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.380283] system 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.383270] system 00:08: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    1.454077] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:19/PNP0C09:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
[    1.454191] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
[    1.454252] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input2
[    1.488961] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[   15.074160] input: Intel HID events as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/INT33D5:00/input/input7
[   15.074244] input: Intel HID 5 button array as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/INT33D5:00/input/input8
[   15.947074] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input9
```

Comment: Why do you think it is a Focaltech touchpad?

Comment: I have dual boot ubuntu with windows 10. It is recognized as focaltech touchpad there.

Comment: I don't think this touchpad is supported by Linux. And it is `FTSC1000:00 2808:509C`.

Comment: isn't FTSC1000:00 2808:509C my two in one's touchscreen?

Comment: Maybe it is, or maybe not.

Comment: What is the laptop model? And is it a PS/2 Focaltech?

Comment: I think it is. Because when I xinput disable 11, it disables my touchscreen.

Comment: lease [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep -i PNP` terminal command.

Comment: Well laptop was given as a scholarship by Education ministry, and it is a Haier Y11C.

Comment: If it is a PS/2 Focaltech, it is fixable.

Comment: I have added the output of dmesg | grep -i PNP.

Comment: There is Focaltech PS/2 driver in the kernel, but it supports `FLT0101, FLT0102, FLT0103` devices. Yours is listed as `FTE0001` most likely. If the protocol is same, maybe the driver will support it. But that needs patching.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: I think you can't if you are asking.

Comment: But I am almost sure that adding `FTE0001` to `focaltech.c` is sufficient.

Comment: And how will that be added?

Comment: You need to compile a kernel, or at least `psmouse.ko` for your kernel.

Comment: And how can I do that? :\

Comment: There are many manuals how to patch and compile a kernel. It's not something you can just tell "how to do".

Comment: Adding FTE0001 to focaltech.c didn't worked. Any other solution?